# Picture upload and download to google appengine is slow

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I am storing pictures in the google datastore that have the size of around 450 x 450 pixels but download speed and especially the upload speed is very slow. Around 5 -15 secs.

In my android app I transform Bitmaps to byte arrays and the byte arrays to a Base64 encoded String which is stored as a Blob in the datastore. For download I do the same the other way around.

I checked the appengine latency but its quite fast about 150ms. So i guess the problem is somehow the bandwith speed...

Does anyone know if this is normal for that picture size? And is it maybe the wrong way how I transform the pictures?
What are usually the techniques to send a bitmap fast?

Thanks for any help!

**Edit**
I am using google cloud endpoints

Comment: ... and the question is? ...

Comment: *And is it maybe the wrong way how I transform the pictures?* only fairy can tell you this without the code ... also only a fairy knows what is a speed of your modem(EDGE or LTE or maybe you are on WIFI) ... if you are sending uncoprressed bitmap you are sending about 1MB => 450x450x4x1.33

Comment: when i download a picture via url that is even bigger than my pictures its super fast. So i need to compress the bitmap somehow before?

Comment: "bigger" how? in dimensions or Kb?

Comment: bigger in dimension and i think kb as well.

Comment: okay i think i am not the only one who is facing the problem with slow speed when uploading blobs via google endpoints. maybe thats just something that doesn't really work well with endpoints

Comment: Don't forget you are using Https, and so your data is encapsulated with SSL.. Personnaly to send a photo to Google Cloud Storage from my Android App (Passing via servlet Google App Engine), it takes less than 3 secondes.. And photo are send in HD resolution (1280x720)

Comment: yeah I am trying now to use a servlet too but can't figure out how I can combine my endpoint with a servlet. Do you maybe know how that works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending files as byte arrays in JSON services and storing the files in the datastore are both pretty bad practices. You should use the BlobStore to upload the images and then use the images service to get a serving URL for the image you uploaded. Store the blob ID and URL in the datastore and whenever you want to view an image in the client - load it directly from Google's CDN by fetching the URL you got. Both upload and download will be orders of magnitude faster this way and even cost you less.

Comment: Hm the problem is I already use google endpoints and don't know how to implement a servlet as well to receive the blobkey and servingurl.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#Java_Uploading_a_blob

You can use an endpoint to get the upload URL.

Comment: yeah uploadUrl is fine but not to get a response after inserting an image to blobstore successfully. So I can't receive the blobkey and ServingUrl with an endpoint.

Comment: You should have an identifier as part of your callback path. For example, map the servlet to "/callback/*" and build the upload URL with createUploadUrl("/callback/" + idFromClient) , and in the callback servlet you can extract this identifier and notify the matching client.

Comment: how can impose relation of parent and child in blob entity and a parent entity ? and how can i implement the blob upload using endpoints rather than web handler . If you have any tutorial can you please provide it.